# how can I get the path to foldername above __DIR__

Tags: php

I know I can use `__ DIR __` to get the path to where I am, but how can I get the path to the folder above `__DIR__` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, you can use the dirname function

```php
$aboveDir = dirname(__DIR__);
```